# Use FFMPEG advanced options via API in C

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use "-re" option via C code using ffmpeg API.
Please let me know how to do it in c program.

Comment: `-re` and `-readrate` are ffmpeg tool options. There's no API access. The basic idea is simple. You get system time at start of reading. Then for each packet, you compare system time elapsed against timestamp interval and decide whether to read the packet or return EAGAIN (or sleep and read).

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Gyan.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.